# Getting my Ruby on Rails page to save the user's email without using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a one page website where visitors will simply be able to submit their email address. The only goal in the database is to get an email (no name, etc). There is only one page visible at first, which is the homepage. If the user submits an email already in use, it sends the user to an error page. If the email is not in use, it sends the user to a success page.

I have asked a question about this previously, and after a lot of comments and trial and error, it appeared that it worked and then it stopped working. When I do Rails C, there is only one user in the system and that user doesnt have an email...

Here is what my user migration looks like :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Here is what my user model looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here is what users/new.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= form_for  @user, as: :post, url: users_path do |f| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <%= f.email_field :email , id: "search", class:"search input" %> <br />
    <%= f.submit "yep", class: "submit input" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:email])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/users/success'
    else
      redirect_to '/users/error'
    end
  end

def show

end

end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "users#new"
  resources :users
end
```

When i run the code, it renders the homepage but when i click on submit, it sends me on a page called show.html.erb with http://localhost:3000/users/error on my brownser. No users are being saved in the console.

EDIT:
My model is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

It is still not working....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197070/discussion-on-question-by-alex-getting-my-ruby-on-rails-page-to-save-the-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here.

1. You're so close, but you're misusing the `as:` attribute of `form_for`. Perhaps you think that will send ***as*** a `POST` request, but instead that is actually wrapping your form params in an object called "post". I saw this in the comments on another thread.

   Remove the `as:` attribute and the helper will again wrap your params in the `user` object. While we're at it, you should also be able to remove the `url:` attribute as well since Rails form helpers are smart enough to infer that this is a new resourceful record and output the `create` URL as well as the `POST` action accordingly.
2. You need your controller to expect a whole "user" object instead of just checking for the `email` param. ALSO, assuming you're on Rails 4 or higher, you need to permit the `email` attribute to be mass-assigned on your `User` object. See the code.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:email)) # Not params[:email]
    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/users/success'
    else
      redirect_to '/users/error'
    end
  end
```

3. Also be careful about duplicate emails with different cases. The default in Rails is case-*sensitive* validation which means "JIM@gmail.com" would not trigger a validation error against "jim@gmail.com". You can fix this with.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

**BONUS!**

Nowadays, it's better to move over to [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) (instead of `form_for`). It's on its way to becoming [the new Rails standard](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a) and also makes a few of these things easier. The one point you'll want to keep in mind is that with `form_with` (and general Rails assumptions), forms are **remote by default**. So if you want to trigger a full page submit/refresh, add `local: true` to your `form_with` helper.

```rb
<%= form_with model: @user, local: true do |f| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <%= f.email_field :email , id: "search", class:"search input" %> <br />
    <%= f.submit "yep", class: "submit input" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! everything seems to work... However, I wrote in show.html.erb 
`<% if '/users/success'%>
yay
<% elsif '/users/error' %>
no
<% end %>` but it only shows 'yay' even if its http://localhost:3000/users/error in the browser

Comment: Here's how Ruby interprets the code you wrote there: `<% if this-string-exists-at-all-which-it-definitely-does-because-its-just-a-string-and-you-wrote-it %> yay...`  You aren't testing for a value of any kind there – you're just testing if that string you wrote is there (which it is becuase you wrote a string there). More on next comment...

Comment: You shouldn't be hitting show.html.erb at all. It should be redirecting to either `/views/users/success.html.erb` or `/views/users/error.html.erb`. The code I provided should produce a `POST` HTML method and therefore trigger the `create` method (not `show`). If it's triggering `show`, then you've got something wrong. I wish I could see the full HTML of your whole page. I wonder if something is expecting the rails-ujs javascript driver and you're not including it. Can you put your whole HTML page output on a Github gist or pastebin so I can see what's going on?

Comment: but surely it automatically redirects me to show.html.erb because theres `resources :users` in my routes ?

Comment: my rails routes also dont show any success or error page... also, my code was bugging because of javascript earlier, so none of the buttons have any javascript.

Comment: I found the answer... i created a static pages controller and just connected them in the routes

Comment: This last bit all sounds non-traditional (and odd), but the best implementation is the one that works so good on you!

Answer (score 2):

change new.html.erb as

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <%= f.email_field :email , id: "search", class:"search input" %> <br />
   <%= f.submit "yep", class: "submit input" %>
  </div>
```

your controller will be

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "yeh!!!!"
  else
   redirect_to new_user_path, notice: "email already registered"
  end
 end

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 private
   def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
   end


end
```

add

`<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>` to your application.html.erb in layouts

rest as your question

Comment: Thats wonderful ! it works and saves unique emails! However, I have one last error : When i try to register the same email address, I get an error... `SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)` While I should be redirected to the error sign in my show page

Comment: here is my show page :
```
<% if '/users/success'%>
yay
<% elsif '/users/error' %>
no
<% end %>
```

Comment: When its a success, im redirected to an empty page with 'yay' written... So i though it was working... but when its a failure, it gives me an error

Comment: Oh I see... so I need to change it to postgres ?

Comment: oh its the same error.. besides, I would like to have html/css code in those 2 pages... so maybe changing it to postgres would allow me to do that in an easier way ?

Comment: unless you think the problem is not because im in sqlite3... in that case it would be a hassle for nothing

Comment: add `validates_uniqueness_of :email` to your model and check

Comment: but `validates_uniqueness_of :email` is what what blocks my whole code from saving... I'm on PG now and not SQLite3 and im having similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `validates_uniqueness_of` in your model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :email
   validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

And

```
def show
   @user = User.find(email: params[:email])
end
```

And if you wanna check all

```
def show
   @user = User.all
end
```

Please try this.

I hope that helpful

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it... It doesn't work... It takes me to the show page and doesnt save the user

Comment: seems like one thing is missing attr_accessor :email in your model as well

Answer (score 0):

As you are using resources in routes so `def show` is called when route is `/users/:id`. That's why its calling show.html.erb file.

When you try to validate an email, then in model write the validation for it

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you ! the def show thing is a lot more clear now ! However, I just tried the validation and it didn't do anything...

Comment: It should work. But still, try with the destructive save method by calling @user.save!. It'll show you the error it's getting.

Comment: ***Validation failed: Email has already been taken*** I typed in a random email... however, there are no new users in my console

Comment: This is from the model validation error. So check your DB users table.